# Correcting address mapping in Google Maps and Google Earth

Tags: data, google-maps, gps, google-earth

We were issued a 911 address when we built our building approximately 3 years ago.

When you go to google maps and google earth and put our address it incorrectly pulls up in town.  The correct placement for our address is  39.006197, -89.149019.  I have updated our address through Google Business and when you physically make the map go to our location and do a right here and select what's here - Our correct address of 544 IL 185 Vandalia, IL 62471 as well as our business comes up.

Is there anyway that to get the search connected so that it will come up correctly when someone needs to use a GPS to find us?

Answer (score 2):

You can submit edits for things like this, and they are often reviewed and applied within a few days, though sometimes it takes longer.

1. Go to [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com)
2. Search for your address
3. Click "send feedback" in the bottom right of the map.
4. Select the option for "Suggest an edit to *your address*"
5. Check the box where it says "Location... Marker is placed incorrectly on the map"
6. Drag the marker to the correct location.
7. Click the blue Submit button.

Note: You might need to be logged in to do this.